# How to silent install dot net 4.5 exe updates offline?

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm using Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit edition. I install windows updates (msu files) offline through a script which does a batch silent install of updates without requesting reboot. Now I need to install dot net 4.5 updates and security patches offline which are exe files. I have got the corresponding exe files of the updates. To do this I will have to open each exe file and wait for the installation to complete. This takes reasonable amount of time.

So, how can I do batch installation dot net 4.5 updates (exe files) without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as using `/?` would have shown you a list of all the command-line parameters supported by the installer, including `/q`, `/passive` and `/norestart`, among others.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my scripts:

64Bit:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R "%~dp0" %%A IN (NDP45*x64*.exe) DO (
        CALL :SUB %%~nA        
    ECHO= Installing KB!KB_NUM!        
    "%%A" /passive /norestart)
>NUL PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

:SUB

SET "KB_NUM=%*"
FOR /F "DELIMS=-" %%B IN ("%KB_NUM:*-KB=%") DO SET "KB_NUM=%%B"
```

32Bit:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R "%~dp0" %%A IN (NDP45*x86*.exe) DO (
        CALL :SUB %%~nA        
    ECHO= Installing KB!KB_NUM!        
    "%%A" /passive /norestart)
>NUL PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

:SUB

SET "KB_NUM=%*"
FOR /F "DELIMS=-" %%B IN ("%KB_NUM:*-KB=%") DO SET "KB_NUM=%%B"
```

Answer (score 0):

dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /qb /passive

Comment: This is for installation from scratch, not for the updates, right?

Comment: Terse answers like yours are very much frowned upon on this site. They provide no context, they can hardly used for similar (but perhaps unrelated) problems by other users, do not allow an understanding of the problem by the original questioner. They should be posted as comments; please refrain from posting them as answers until you have the reputatin to post comments.

Comment: Can we be provided some context on the reason using those arguments is the solution to the author's question?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.